# Cumulative sum over matrix diagonals

Tags: r, cumulative-sum

The input is a square matrix with mostly `0` and some `1`. The goal is to take a (sort of) cumulative sum of consecutive `1`s along the diagonals of the input matrix.

```
#Input
ind = rbind(cbind(x = c(2, 3, 1, 2 , 3),
                  y = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)))
m1 = replace(matrix(0, 5, 5), ind, 1)
m1
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
#[1,]    0    0    1    0    0
#[2,]    1    0    0    1    0
#[3,]    0    1    0    0    1
#[4,]    0    0    0    0    0
#[5,]    0    0    0    0    0

#Desired Output
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
# [1,]    0    0    0    0    0
# [2,]    0    0    0    0    0
# [3,]    0    2    0    0    3
# [4,]    0    0    0    0    0
# [5,]    0    0    0    0    0
```

I've got a `for` loop that does the job but is there a better way?

```
#Current Approach
m2 = m1
for (i in 2:nrow(m1)){
    for (j in 2:nrow(m1)){
        if (m1[i-1, j-1] == 1 & m1[i, j] == 1){
            m2[i, j] = m2[i - 1, j - 1] + m2[i, j]
            m2[i - 1, j - 1] = 0
        }
    }
}
m2
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
#[1,]    0    0    0    0    0
#[2,]    0    0    0    0    0
#[3,]    0    2    0    0    3
#[4,]    0    0    0    0    0
#[5,]    0    0    0    0    0
```

Comment: write the loop in `Rcpp` and you'll likely get a speed boost on larger matrices

Comment: You could use a row/col difference to do the initial split - `row(m1) - col(m1)` - beyond that it probably gets a bit tricky.

Comment: The loop is likely to be faster than anything with `row` or `col` functions. I like answers that use them but there create logical matrices as large as the original.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the example it seems that every diagonal is all zeros or else is a sequence of ones followed by zeros.  We assume that that is always the case.

First form a function `cum` which takes a diagonal `x` and outputs a vector of zeros the same length except that position `sum(x)` is to be set to `sum(x)` .

Then apply that function across diagonals using `ave`. `row(m1)-col(m1)` is constant on diagonals and can be used for grouping.

```
cum <- function(x, s = sum(x)) replace(0 * x, s, s)
ave(m1, row(m1) - col(m1), FUN = cum)

##      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
## [1,]    0    0    0    0    0
## [2,]    0    0    0    0    0
## [3,]    0    2    0    0    3
## [4,]    0    0    0    0    0
## [5,]    0    0    0    0    0
```

If the sequence of ones on a diaongal need not start at the beginning of the diagonal but it is still true that there is only one sequence of ones at most on each diagonal then use this in place of `cum` above:

```
cum <- function(x, s = sum(x)) replace(0 * x, s + which.max(x) - 1, s)
```

If there can be more than one sequence of ones on a diagonal then use this in place of `cum` above:

```
library(data.table)
cum <- function(x) {
  ave(x, rleid(x), FUN = function(x, s = sum(x)) replace(0 * x, s, s))
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your loop in Rcpp

```r
library(Rcpp)

cppFunction('NumericMatrix diagcumsum( NumericMatrix m1 ) {

  int i = 0;
  int j = 0;
  int n_row = m1.nrow();

  NumericMatrix res = Rcpp::clone( m1 );

  for( i = 1; i < n_row; i++ ) {
    for( j = 1; j < n_row; j++ ) {
      if( m1( (i-1), (j-1) ) == 1 && m1( i, j ) == 1 ) {
        res(i, j) = res( (i-1), (j-1) ) + res(i, j);
        res( (i-1), (j-1) ) = 0;
      }
    }
  }
  return res;
}')

diagcumsum( m1 )

#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
# [1,]    0    0    0    0    0
# [2,]    0    0    0    0    0
# [3,]    0    2    0    0    3
# [4,]    0    0    0    0    0
# [5,]    0    0    0    0    0
```